# Edittext outline box not visible

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext

I have 2 EditText's in a layout. For some reason, the border outline that shows in the preview here(http://gyazo.com/7cb0d1d2c5807e65f65164957b4d13b8) doesn't show when I run the app on my phone or on the emulator(http://gyazo.com/428bb31a974e43ccb52aaaee61f3b355). I would like to see that box that outlines the Edittext's in the preview screen.

If anyone could try and see what the issue is, that would be great, thanks.

XML containing the 2 Edittext's:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_medium"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".List" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text1andText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Text2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Text2" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Theme problem. Your device is using Holo Theme. Try to change your Theme as desire (ui.light /ui.dark)in your application manifest.